# Is there a way to check if two objects are aliased in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, alias

Is there a way to detect if two objects in Java are aliased to each other? In C I guess we can check the memory addresses that two pointers are pointing to. But is there a way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In java, the variables are references so you can compare them using `==` to see if they refer to the same object.

```
Object a = ...
Object b = a;
boolean areSame = (a == b); //Will be true.
```

Comment: What if the class overrides the equals method?

Comment: +1, nice concise answer, wish I could upvote more than once. :)

Comment: If you want to compare the actual objects, you must explicitly call `.equals()`. `==` will always compare just the references for objects.

Comment: @user1260682 `equals()` method is something different from the reference-equality sign `==`.

Comment: You can override `equals` but you can't override `==`

Comment: I would use the term `isSame` instead of `areEqual` which can be confused with `equals`

Answer (score 4):

```
if (obj1 == obj2) {
   // both refrences are pointing to same object
}
```